# check if PDO query returns results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Assume I have this piece of code:

```
foreach($creds as $cred){
    $prev_fut = $pdo->query("SELECT importo FROM incassi_prev WHERE
    data_prev='$data_fut' AND incasso=0 AND
    id_cre='{$cred['id_cre']}'")->fetch();
    if(count($prev_fut)>0){
        //I have found a result
    }else{
        //I have found nothing
    }
}
```

NOTE: It is an internal query for my application with no data posted by user so I don't worry about SQL injections.

I use to check if `count($prev_fut)>0` to see if the query is returning data (if I find any row in the db with these criterias).
My question is:

> is this check enough to verify that the query has at least a result? Is it better to perform any other check?

The question is mostly coming from my thoughts about this being in a for loop and is related to the option of emptying/unset the $prev_fut array before starting a new iteration of for loop.

Comment: `if(count($pdo->query("SELECT....")->fetchAll()))` and done. But, what tickles my 5.5th sense is - why do you need to check if a record exists? Is it related to inserting / updating based on existence of a record?

Comment: yes. It is and I have to perform some logics before doing Insert or update. My concern is not to loose data if I don't trigger the right event. I'm writing a financial app and numbers means money there!

Comment: Can you shed some more light on it? I've been in financial market for past 7 years, I got burned on all sorts of things and what tingles here is that you're doing some sort of integrity check before performing db queries which relate to financial transactions. If you are doing that, then trust me - you will get royally effed. It seems what you have here is an XY problem, do you want to review what you're doing maybe to save yourself some time in the future?

Comment: I have a table with a prevision of an income (let's say in june). If the prevision is wrong (I have not received the money when expected) I have to postpone it to the next month (july). So if there isn't already another prevision in july I can just update the one in june changing the date. If there is I have to fetch it, sum the two, delete the one in june and then update the one in july with the sum of the two previsions. This is the logic I have to undergo and I cannot see any smarter idea by now

Comment: Ok, and in this system you described - where's the transaction history? You're deleting financial data, are you able to track your steps back? Reason I'm asking all this is - you can't deal with data integrity by checking db info in php and then insert / update - you will be hit by concurrency, unless your system is such that only 1 process alters the db.

Comment: let's say that I solved the concurrency issue by assigning this task only to a role to a single user (users for this app are 10 and are on a intranet). By now I haven't managed my client to realize why the rollback functionalities are usefull! ;)

Comment: Well, it appears that you have a few things to iron out and the whole bunch of suggestions that I'd hand out might prove bad at this stage. If it works for now, and if the answer posted satisfies you - then that should be ok for now. I really do wish you the best of luck with finances and may you get no screwups along your way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchColumn` returns a single value of the next row in the result set. `count` counts the length of an array. Since `fetchColumn` can't return an array (for most database implementations), using `count` on it is wrong. You want to test whether `$prev_fut` is `false` or not. `false` would indicate that no result could be fetched, while anything else means a result was fetched:

```
if ($prev_fut !== false) ..
```

Having said that, you should really use a `COUNT()` in the database and check that value:

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...')->fetchColumn();
if ($result > 0) ..
```

It's much more efficient to have the database count and summarise the result than fetching an entire result set into PHP just for this simple check.

Comment: Woah! You are right! Editing my question for the typo error but this is a good point when I return a single value!

Comment: If it's just a boolean check you don't even need `COUNT(*)` ... you could just do `SELECT 1 FROM ... `